# How to call a php script in server from python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to run the php script which is in my server from the python project which is in my local machine.

I have tried following till now

Python Side:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import json
import sys
import os

def php(script_path):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['php', script_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = p.communicate()[0]
    return result

image_dimensions_json = str(php("http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX/logistic_admin/test1.php"))
dic = json.loads(image_dimensions_json)
print str(dic["0"]) + "|" + str(dic["1"])
```

php side:

```
test1.php

<?php
echo(json_encode(getimagesize($argv[1])));

?>
```

But I am facing following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\folder\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    image_dimensions_json = str(php("http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX/logistic_admin/test1.php"))
  File "D:\folder\test.py", line 16, in php
    p = subprocess.Popen(['php', script_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You probably need to use the urllib or requests module

Comment: @Rakesh how to use it. Can you give me an example.

Comment: Why are you calling your PHP over an HTTP web server? Are both PHP and Python on the same server or not?

Comment: @delboy1978uk no my php code is in server and python is in my desktop

Comment: ah ok fair enough then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `urllib` module.

**Ex:**

```
import urllib

def php(script_path):
    urlData = urllib.urlopen(script_path)
    return urlData.read()
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

or you can use requests module:

```
import requests

def req(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
```

or urllib2 module:

```
import urllib2
def req(url):
   f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   return f.read()
```